# Could not redirect the file names that are being deleted to an output csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Am trying to delete files older than x days and would like to know which file is being deleted.

Am using below powershell script, it doesnt work

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$path = $args[0]

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force | select Name,LastWriteTime | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $args[1]
```

Am passing first argument as path where files are there.
Second argument is the output file which should contain the file and date modified values of those which gets deleted.

The above code works fine for deletion, but doesnt redirects the file names and the last modified values which got deleted.

If I use below code, it only redirects the file names and last modified values but files doesnt get deleted.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | select Name,LastWriteTime | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $args[1] | Remove-Item -Force
```

Using below command to run it -

```
./OlderFiles_Cleansing.ps1 'C:\Dev\PS' 'C:\dev\CleanedFiles_01062016.csv'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the Export-Csv nor the Remove-Item Cmdlet return the collection you pipe in and so make it impossible to work with the items further in the pipeline.

You can do following though - split the command:

```
$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -Attributes !Directory | Where-Object CreationTime -lt $limit  
$filesToDelete | select Name,LastWriteTime | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $args[1] 
$filesToDelete | Remove-Item -Force
```

Note I have improved the way of detecting that an item is a file using the 
*Attributes* param and so could simplify the Where pipe part

Comment: Thanks a lot Honzajscz!